# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reloadablePropertyPostProcessor'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am trying to implement https://github.com/jamesmorgan/ReloadablePropertiesAnnotation in Spring and can't figure out the problem.

I have tried other solution that states that add component scan package properly but seems, that is not a solution for this problem.

Looked for dependency through xml: It tries to create bean ReloadablePropertyPostProcessor and inject values using constructor which is dependent on ReadablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Here is the stacktrace:

```
    **org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reloadablePropertyPostProcessor' defined in file** [/Users/xxxxx/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/spring3-mvc-maven-xml-hello-world/WEB-INF/classes/com/demo/design/properties/internal/ReloadablePropertyPostProcessor.class]: **Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type** [com.demo.design.properties.internal.ReadablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.demo.design.properties.internal.ReadablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.demo.design.properties.internal.ReadablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at 
...
...
...
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.demo.design.properties.internal.ReadablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}**
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:997)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:867)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
        ... 37 more
```

Here is my spring-reloadableProperties.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
">

    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-defaultConfiguration.xml" />

    <bean
        class="com.demo.design.properties.internal.ReloadablePropertyPostProcessor">
        <constructor-arg ref="propertyConfigurator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="eventNotifier" />
        <constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
    </bean>

    <bean  id="propertyConfigurator"
        class="com.demo.design.properties.internal.ReadablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <constructor-arg ref="eventNotifier" />
        <constructor-arg ref="propertyResolver" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
<!--                <value>file:${CONFIG_DIR}/global.properties</value> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```